# About some bijections

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $H=ℤ^{r},\ r>0$, and $K=ℤ/nℤ,\ n>0$. Let $G$ be an abelian group such that $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ with $G=H+K$ and $H\cap K=\{0\}$. Then there is an isomorphism $\phi:H×K→G$ defined by:

$$φ:H×K→G$$

$$(Q,T)→φ(Q,T)=Q+T$$

or

$$(α_1,\dots,α_{r},T)→ψ(α_1,\dots,α_{r},T)=∑_{k=1}^{r}α_{k}P_{k}+T$$

where $Q=∑_{k=1}^{r}α_{k}P_{k}$, $α_{k}∈ℤ$. (Here ${P_1,P_2,\dots,P_{r}}$ are $r$ independent points of infinite order in $G$, i.e., $P_{k}=(x_{k},y_{k})∈\mathbb Q^2,\ k=1,..,r$ such that if $∑_{k=1}^{r}α_{k}P_{k}=0$, $α_{k}∈ℤ$, then $α_{k}=0$ for all $k=1,..,r$.)

My **question** is:

Can we find non-trivial bijections $f_{k}:ℤ→ℤ,\ k=1,...,r$, such that the map

$$(f_1(α_1),...,f_{r}(α_{r}),T)→ψ(f_1(α_1),...,f_{r}(α_{r}),T)=∑_{k=1}^{r}f_{k}(α_{k})P_{k}+T$$

remains bijective from $H×K$ to $G$?

Comment: "Reals, integers..."? You begin by asking about an apparently general abelian group which is the direct product of two of its subgroups. Then you decide, god knows why, that the first factor's elements can be written as $\,r-$ vectors , with $\,P_k\,$ components or something being who-knows-what. And then you introduce $\,A,B\,$ which, apparently again, you want them to be subsets (subgroups?) of the integers and of the reals, and bijections and... Why won't you better give us *the exact* data you're thinking of?

Comment: @  DonAntonio: I edit the question to makes things clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's really *bijections* you are interested in, then *any* set of bijections $f_{k}$ will do.

I am working under the assumption that $H$ is a free abelian group on the $P_{k}$, that is, $H$ is abelian, $P_{k} \in H$, and any element of $H$ can be uniquely written as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{r} \alpha_{k} P_{k},
$$
for $\alpha_{k} \in \Bbb{Z}$. (In your assumptions I can only find the *uniqueness* part, but from the way you write it, it appears that the $P_{k}$ also span $H$.)

Then, whenever the $f_{k}$ are bijections, the map $H \to H$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{r} \beta_{k} P_{k} \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^{r} f_{k}(\beta_{k}) P_{k}
$$
is a bijection, since any $r$-tuple $(\alpha_{1}, \dots, \alpha_{r})$ can be uniquely written as 
$$
(\alpha_{1}, \dots, \alpha_{r})
=
(f_{1}(\beta_{1}), \dots, f_{r}(\beta_{r})).
$$

Comment: @ Andreas Caranti: Yes, $H$ is a free abelian group on the $P i$. Thank you.

Comment: @Chaos, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I have read through this (very confusingly worded) question.  There are many things that need clarification but I will attempt to answer it as stated.

First, let's note that this has nothing to do with the group $K$.  It operates completely distinctly from the $f_k$'s you're asking about since $H\cap K$ is trivial.  What you're asking is a question about the group $H$.

Second, note that you're asking about $f_k$ from the reals to the integers, but then you're applying the $f_k$ to $\alpha_k$ which are assumed to be integers.  So at the very least we can say that the $f_k$ domain is the integers, simplifying things a bit.

So the answer depends on

1. whether your $P_k$ are linearly independent,
2. whether the $\alpha_k$ comprise the entirety of $B$, and
3. the nature of $G$, in particular if it is torsion-free.

Each of these could be exploited to give you a "cheap" counterexample where your functions couldn't be found.  It may be possible to find a situation in which this *does* work, but I suspect that it will not be helpful for me to find one until you refine the conditions of your question.  (And I'd rather not do so until it has been reworded so I know I'm not wasting my time.)

Comment: @ Alexander Gruber: I edit the question to makes things clear.

Comment: @Chaos So you mean bijections, *not* isomorphisms?

Comment: Yes. Any kind of bijections.